# Foggy film (I’m new)

Tags: troubleshooting, fujifilm, yashica

Hey guys so I’m pretty new to the film/analog photography. I took some pictures in my London trip got them developed and they all came out foggy and I can’t see anything. I would appreciate some help or tips so next time I won’t make the same mistake I use the Yashica FX-Dse quartz my film I used was Fujicolor 200 [image]

Comment: Have you ever shot a successful roll of film with this camera? What conditions were you shooting in? That is, was it outdoors in sunlight? Dark interiors? A mixture? Do you understand the exposure triangle? What aperture setting(s) were you using? Did the shutter sound to you like it was operating normally?

Comment: What do the edges of your negative show? The frame numbers and the film type are always easily readable unless there was a problem with development...

Comment: @BobT I don’t have my negative yet since I got the picture send today from the developer:)

Comment: @osullic Yes I did so I was confused, it was outdoors but the sun was shining my exposer settings where on 200 (since I was outdoors) and yes the shutter was operating normally

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a processing problem -- it's what I'd expect to see if the bleach or fixer steps in lab processing didn't happen.

If you have the negatives, and assuming they show a milky surface with the color image superposed on it, you should take them back to the lab that did the processing (or another lab you trust) and ask them to rerun only the bleach and fix part of the process.

Of course, if you processed these yourself, using a C-41 kit, your blix is dead; rerunning only the blix step of the process with fresh solution will correct this problem.